# How to specify what should not be in email address using Fluent validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

In ASP.NET Core-6 Web API Application, I am implementing Fluent validation. I have this validation for email.

```
RuleFor(user => user.Email.ToLower())
    .MaximumLength(100).WithMessage("Email must not exceed 100 characters.")
    .Must(BeUniqueEmail).WithMessage("The specified Email Address already exists.")
    .EmailAddress().WithMessage("Kindly enter a valid Email Address. ERROR!");
```

Using Fluent validation, how do I validate that the Email Address should not contain "embryco"?

Answer (score 0):

You can you can add regex to validate that the Email Address should not contain `embryco`:

```
RuleFor(user => user.Email.ToLower())
     .MaximumLength(100).WithMessage("Email must not exceed 100 characters.")
     .Must(BeUniqueEmail).WithMessage("The specified Email Address already exists.")
     .EmailAddress().WithMessage("Kindly enter a valid Email Address. ERROR!")
      //add regex to validate
     .Matches("^((?!embryco).)*$").WithMessage("Email Address should not contain embryco");
```